# google-chrome: Failed to generate minidump

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Google chrome was hung so I killed it.

When I try to restart it, I see:

```
$ google-chrome-stable                                                                        
Failed to generate minidump.Bus error
```

How do I start chrome now?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my `/home` partition was full (and `chrome`'s error messages are somewhat lacking).

Check your partitions for free space with:

```
$ df -h
```